# Turning multidimensional arrays into databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I'm trying to turn a huge configuration array in PHP, that looks like this

```
$config['festival'] = 
array
(
    'title' => 'USF Tango Festival',
    'tableLayout' => array
    (
        'registration' => array
        (
            array('firstName','text'),
            array('lastName','text'),
            array('phone','text'),
            array('email','text'),
            array('hearAboutFestival','text'),
            array('danceAs','enum(\'Leader\', \'Follower\', \'Both\')'),
            array('student','tinyint(1)')
        ),
        'experience' => array
        (
            array('options','text'),
            array('lunchMeat','enum(\'Ham\',\'Turkey\',\'Vegetarian\')'),
            array('lunchBread','enum(\'White\',\'Wheat\')'),
            array('dinnerPref','enum(\'Chicken\',\'Beef\',\'Vegetarian\')')
        )
    ),
    'pageLayout' => array
    (
        'registration' => array
        (
            'jqueryRules' =>
<<<EOT
    'firstName': 'required',
    'lastName': 'required',
    'phone': {
        required: true,
        phoneUS: true
    },
    'email': {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    'danceAs': 'required',
    'partner': 'required',
    'partnerMatching': {
        required: function() {
            return $("input[name='partner']").val() == 0;
        }
    },
    'partnerName': {
        required: function() {
            return $("input[name='partner']").val() == 1;
        }
    }
EOT
    ,
        'inputs' => array
        (
            array
            (
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'firstName',
                'fullName' => 'First Name',
                'required' => true,
                'separateDiv' => false
            ),
            array
            (
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'lastName',
                'fullName' => 'Last Name',
                'required' => true,
                'separateDiv' => false
            ),
            array
            (
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'phone',
                'fullName' => 'Phone number',
                'required' => true,
                'separateDiv' => false
            ),
            array
            (
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'email',
                'fullName' => 'Email address',
                'required' => true,
                'separateDiv' => false
            ),
            array
            (
                'type' => 'text',               
                'name' => 'hearAboutFestival',
                'separateDiv' => false,
                'fullName' => 'How did you hear about the festival?',
                'required' => false
            ),
            array
            (
                'type' => 'select',
                'name' => 'danceAs',
                'fullName' => 'You dance as a...',
                'required' => true,
                'separateDiv' => false,
                'options' => array(array('leader','Leader'),array('follower','Follower'),array('both','Both'))
            ),
            array
            (
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'student',
                'value' => '1',
                'separateDiv' => false,
                'fullName' => 'I am a student',
                'required' => false
            )
        )
    )
```

and

```
'options' => array
(
    'busMilonga' => array
    (
        'price' => 20,
        'student' => false,
        'name' => 'Tango on the Town Bus milonga',
        'description' => 'A bus milonga!'
    ),
    'thursdayMilonga' => array
    (
        'price' => 10,
        'student' => false,
        'name' => 'Thursday Kickoff Milonga',
        'description' => 'The un-official kick off milonga!'
    ),
    'saturdayPass' => array
    (
        'price' => 90,
        'student' => true,
        'name' => 'Saturday pass',
        'description' => 'Includes all Saturday workshops and milongas'
    ),
    'sundayPass' => array
    (
        'price' => 80,
        'student' => true,
        'name' => 'Sunday pass',
        'description' => 'Includes all Sunday workshops, the jam session, and milonga'
    ),
    'milongaPass' => array
    (
        'price' => 70,
        'earlyBird' => 50, //array(50,60),
        'student' => true,
        'name' => 'Milonga Pass',
        'description' => 'Includes entrance to all night milongas'
    ),
    'dinnerPass' => array
    (
        'price' => 20,
        'student' => false,
        'name' => 'Dinner pass',
        'description' => 'Includes Saturday dinner'
    ),
    'lunchPass' => array
    (
        'price' => 10,
        'student' => false,
        'name' => 'Saturday lunch',
        'description' => 'Includes lunch on Saturday'
    )
),
'info' => array
(
    'instructors' => array('Instructors'),
    'hour' => array('10','11','12','01','02','03'),
    'min' => array('15','30','45','00'),
    'tod' => array('AM','PM'),
    'day' => array('Friday','Saturday','Sunday'),
    'level' => array('Beginner','Intermediate','Advanced'),
    'place' => array('REC 107','REC 033','REC 005'),
    'sessions' => array
    (
        3, // days
        array
        (
            'Friday', // day name
            3, // sessions on this day
            array
            (
                3, // workshops in session
                '1100AM' // time
            ), 
            array
            (
                3, 
                '0100PM' 
            ), 
            array
            (
                1,
                '0230PM'
            ) // 1,4
        ),
        array('Saturday', // 2,0
            3, // 2,1
            array(1,'1030AM'), //2,2
            array(3,'1145AM'), // 2,3
            array(3,'0145PM') // 2,4
        ),
        array
        (
            'Sunday', // 3,0
            3, // 3,1
            array(1,'1115AM'), // 3,2
            array(3,'1230PM'), // 3,3
            array(3,'0230PM') // 3,4
        )
    )
)
```

into a database. I'm thinking I could make a few tables, titled something like config.event.festival but then it would get cumbersome since I would have to create a table for each array under the array...

I want to avoid using JSON encoding or serializing, so that I keep the data all relational and clean looking but I don't know any other way other than just keeping one big configuration file rather than a database.

Comment: So you want the audience to design your database structure and write the code for you ? PHP and MYSQL are different. MYSQL don't have any idea what a PHP array is. So there is no single-off way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not asking for the code, I'm asking for a design idea to put my configuration file into a database. I understand the difference between the programming language (PHP) and the database (MySQL) and I know you can't just put arrays in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the sample you provided represents a truncated view of your whole data structure, this could be done with three tables.

## festival

- festival_id
- title

## layout

- layout_id
- festival_id
- layout_type_id
- type
- name
- fullName
- required
- separateDiv

## layout_type

- layout_type_id
- name

The festival table would keep your high-level meta data about the event page. The layout table would contain meta data about each of the elements on the page. And finally, the layout_type table would allow you to identify different element types that should be on a given page.

This should get you started and allow you to modify as necessary.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how this would look? I think this might be a good solution but I wouldn't know how to start. How would I use layout_type? Like: layout_type_id = 1, name = input ?

Comment: I will update the example to show a less truncated view of my configuration file.

Comment: Your expanded config block makes it obvious that this is not a complete answer to your question (I can see a need for 2-3 more tables to handle tables, input options, and possibly other elements). Also,  I hesitate to offer more of a solution than I have provided already since I don't know your full requirements. However, you should be able to take the sample config snippets you put in the question and apply it to the above tables. This should give you enough of an idea that you could take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// To save multidimensional array into database:

$confIn = serialize($config);

// Save serialized config into database

// To get it from database, query the database and get serialized value

$confOut = serialize($confIn);

// Check if its ok

var_export($confOut);
```

More about serialize function: [Serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

The good thing with this approach is you can use only one column in database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to avoid serializing the data because I want to be able to be able to keep the relational structure together if possible.